# Sending apple push notification using stream_context via Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, apple-push-notifications

I am attempting to send apple push notifications using the following sample PHP script obtained here ,http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

:

```
function sendPNotification(){
    // Put your device token here (without spaces):
    $deviceToken = '0f744707bebcf7......';

    // Put your private key's passphrase here:
    $passphrase = 'pu...';

    // Put your alert message here:
    $message = 'My first push notification!';

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

    // Open a connection to the APNS server
    $fp = stream_socket_client(
        'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
        $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

    if (!$fp)
        exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);


   //Proceed to send message if all is well......

}
sendPNotification();
```

This code is held in a page, sendPNFunction.php.

When I access sendPNFunction.php via a browser, all is well.  The connection works, and the message is sent.

However, when I attempt to reach the page via an Ajax call using jQuery, the connection fails every time.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: php generaly wouldn't care HOW it was invoked. "enter url into address bar and hit enter" v.s. "do an ajax call in jquery" are both fundamentally just http calls, and minus a few minor technical differences, are exactly the same thing as far as the server and PHP are concerned.

Comment: I was able to remedy this issue by moving around the certificate files to the local folder where the page calling the functions described above are located.  Initially, I was storing them in the root, but when calling via Ajax this configuration was a no go.